# cannot build cuba platform

Tags: gradle, cuba-platform

I am unable to build the cuba platform plugin I am assuming because gradle cannot download the necessary artifacts.  I set the proxy:

gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8118
gradle -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8118

However, it still fails:

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your proxy allows you to access the repository? You can check it if you write a trivial Java program accessing our repository URL (https://repo.cuba-platform.com/content/groups/work) and run it with the same settings.

Comment: Well, so if I manually navigate to one of those URLs, I get a forbidden error - it looks like the URL requires authentication.  So, I would expect the same exception in gradle, but instead I get a timeout.  Once I get the auth exception, then I would look to resolve that problem, but I'm not even there yet in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must use gradlew which uses 3.1, version 3.1 does NOT work.